# Thymeleaf dropdown with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using two tables:

1. Terminals
2. Repairs

with a many (Repairs) to one (Terminal) relationship. I am trying to populate a Thymeleaf form to create a new repair. One of the fields is a dropdown to select the Terminal but I am getting a ***java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A null value cannot be assigned to a primitive type*** error. This is my code:

**Entity:**

```
public class Repair {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long repairId;
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Terminal.class)
@JoinColumn(nullable = false)
private Terminal terminal;
@Column(name = "date_received", nullable = false)
private Date dateReceived;
@Column(name = "date_ready")
private Date dateReady;
@Column(name = "fault")
private String fault;
@Column(name = "solution")
private String solution;
//constructors, getters & setters

public class Terminal {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(nullable = false)
private long terminalId;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String ptid;
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = TerminalModel.class)
@JoinColumn(nullable = false)
private TerminalModel terminalModel;
//constructors, getters & setters
```

**Controller:**

```
@GetMapping("/repair/repairs/new")
public String createRepairForm(Model model){
    List<Terminal> terminals = terminalService.getAllTerminals();
    Repair repair = new Repair();
    model.addAttribute("terminals", terminals);
    model.addAttribute("repair", repair);
    return "repair/create-repair";
}
```

**View:**

```
<form th:action="@{/repairs}" th:object="${repair}" method="POST">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Date Received</label>
                    <input type="text" name="dateReceived" th:field = "*{dateReceived}" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Date Received"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Date Ready</label>
                    <input type="text" name="dateReady" th:field = "*{dateReady}" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Date Ready"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Fault</label>
                    <input type="text" name="fault" th:field = "*{fault}" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Fault"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Solution</label>
                    <input type="text" name="solution" th:field = "*{solution}" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Solution"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="terminal">Terminal:</label>
        <select id="terminal" name="terminal.terminalId" th:field="*{terminal.terminalId}">
            <option value="">-- Select Terminal --</option>
            <option th:each="terminal : ${terminals}" th:value="${terminal.terminalId}" th:text="${terminal.ptid}">
            </option>
        </select>
                </div>
                <div class="footer-body">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Submit </button>
                </div>

            </form>
```

This is part of the trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@jakarta.persistence.Id @jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue @jakarta.persistence.Column long] for value 'null'
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.assertNotPrimitiveTargetType(GenericConversionService.java:335) ~[spring-core-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleResult(GenericConversionService.java:328) ~[spring-core-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:193) ~[spring-core-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConvertingPropertyEditorAdapter.setAsText(ConvertingPropertyEditorAdapter.java:60) ~[spring-core-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.util.SpringSelectedValueComparator.exhaustiveCompare(SpringSelectedValueComparator.java:173) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.util.SpringSelectedValueComparator.isSelected(SpringSelectedValueComparator.java:90) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.processor.SpringOptionFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(SpringOptionFieldTagProcessor.java:68) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.processor.AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.java:187) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    ... 52 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A null value cannot be assigned to a primitive type
    ... 61 common frames omitted

2023-08-25T08:48:04.115+02:00 ERROR 28912 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring6.processor.SpringOptionFieldTagProcessor' (template: "repair/create-repair" - line 60, col 17)] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A null value cannot be assigned to a primitive type
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you please show the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: I have included the trace.

Comment: What is part of the trace? The full stack trace is not included in your question.

Comment: Does the error happen when loading the thymeleaf edit page or does it happen when sending the data (POSTing to `/repairs`)?

Comment: The error happens when loading the page (repair/create-repair)

Comment: Does the error still occur if you remove `<option value="">-- Select Terminal --</option>`? Can you show the `Terminal` class?

Comment: When I remove reference to the Terminal in Thymeleaf the error disspears. I have included the Terminal class.

Comment: When saying "reference to the Terminal", are you talking about the `<option value="">-- Select Terminal --</option>` or the whole `<select>` element? Did you try making `terminalId` a `Long` instead of a `long`?

Comment: I changed to _Long_  and it worked, thank you @dan1st

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates that a primitive type (such as `int`, `long`, ...) cannot have `null` assigned to it. The Java language does not allow this.

If you want to allow `null` values, you need to use a wrapper (e.g. `Integer`, `Long`, ...).

I see you have `private long terminalId;`. Try changing this to `private Long terminalId;`

PS: A better alternative is to use a dedicated form data object so you only need to change it to `Long` in the form data object and keep your entity like you want. See https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/05/23/form-handling-with-thymeleaf/ for more info.

Comment: Using the wrapper class (_Long_) worked @wim-deblauwe